# Add attributes to element from JSON using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue.js V1 and want to take some JSON like this:

```
{ "class": "foo bar", "max-length": 25 }
```

And map it to an element so something like this:

```
<input type="text" {{ json }} />
```

And that renders as:

```
<input type="text" class="foo bar" max-length="25" />
```

I have tried this with a method `<input type="text" {{ convertJSON(json) }} />` where `convertJSON` creates a string from the JSON. This doesn't work. When I transpile with it vueify it gives me the error “Found camel case attribute”.

Is this possible with Vue?

EDIT: I want to do it without having to go through each attribute manually; I already know how to bind them. I wondered if it was possible to do it dynamically. I suspect it isn't but wanted to check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an object of attributes to [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind). This works in v1 and v2.

In your case, assuming `json` is the JSON object:

```
<input type="text" v-bind="json" />
```

[Here's an example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/b1a5cwef/)

Answer (score 0):

This syntax will most probably fail - vue is run after html is rendered - you will already have major html problems here because it will try to interpret {{ json }} as html attributes.

However you can always bind you data

```
<div v-bind:class="myJson.class" v-bind:max-length="myJson['max-length']">
...
```

If you are really interest in binding everything with one json you can simply create a component that wraps a basic input like

```
<template>
    <inputv-bind:class="data.class" v-bind:max-length="data['max-length']">
</template>
```

And define a single prop here

```
// .. component definition
props: ['data'], 
// ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `v-bind`.

For example

```
<input type="text" v-bind:class=[myClass] v-bind:maxlength=[myLength] />

data: {
  myClass: 'foo',
  myLength: 25
}
```

```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2n9h9vpk/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom directive that takes the json as a parameter and automatically turns each key-value pair into an arrtibute on the element.

Comment: This is exactly what `v-bind` does when you pass it an object, no need for a custom directive.